# How to drop a database with metacharacters in the name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to drop database with metacharacters in the name. The database name is `#mysql50#lost+found`.

I'm connecting in mysql as root user. I tried to put backslashes like in a shell command:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> DROP DATABASE '\#mysql50\#lost\+found' ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

It doesn't work

Comment: this seems like it belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backticks for the object name; not backslashes to escape single characters:

```
mysql> drop database `#really-bad+name`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *specific problem* in the question the database `#mysql50#lost+found` is an artefact from the filesystem mounted on (probably) `/var/lib/mysql` which has a special `lost+found`  directory reserved for recovery when using `fsck`.

So this directory should be left alone by telling MariaDB to ignore it. In `/etc/my.cnf` or other similar place, add:

```
ignore-db-dir=lost+found
```

and restart the database server.

refs: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ignore-db-dir) / [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld-options/#-ignore-db-dir)

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/lost+found/` then `sudo service mysql restart` is what worked for me.

Comment: @Ryan the lost+found directory is a special directory dedicated to salvages and repairs made by e2fsck where it links orphaned files found. It's probably not advised to remove it.

Comment: You're probably right, but in my specific scenario, I've been spending the whole day trying to figure out this mess: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/262072/18098

Comment: @Ryan I don't see a relation with the issue I answered to